# Count the number of strings in one column common with strings in other column

Tags: r

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
V1    | V2
------+------------
a,b,c | x,y,z,w,t,a
c,d   | d,z,c,t
a,b,d | a,f,t,b,d
```

where the count of strings in `V1` is always under 3. I need an R code which tells the number of strings common with `V2`:

```
V1    | V2          | Count
------+-------------+------
a,b,c | x,y,z,w,t,a | 1
c,d   | d,z,c,t     | 2
a,b,d | a,f,t,b,d   | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mapply(function(x,y) sum(x %in% y),
   strsplit(df$V1,",", fixed=TRUE),strsplit(df$V2,",", fixed=TRUE))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

**Data**

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = c("a,b,c", "c,d", "a,b,d"), V2 = c("x,y,z,w,t,a", 
"d,z,c,t", "a,f,t,b,d")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks @nicola. Can you please suggest a way to find the % count also. i.e.   V1     |V2          |Count |%
         ------+------------+-------+
         a,b,c|x,y,z,w,t,a|1       |33.33
          c,d  |d,z,c,t      |2       |100
        a,b,d |a,f,t,b,d   |3       |100